# Do all Careers employers need to offer work from home opportunities?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I saw the advertisement below and I'm wondering whether all companies who join Careers must offer work from home opportunities. That might be a good reason to join Careers. It's rather unusual in Germany to work (almost) full time from home.

[image: Work From Home Advertisement]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, employers have no requirement to offer jobs that allow for remote work.

They do have to *list* wether or not they allow for remote work; you can filter on jobs that explicitly state remote work is part of the job:

[image: Circled *allows remote* checkbox in the Careers search interface]

At the time of this answer there are [4 job listings](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&type=any&location=Germany&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&allowsremote=true) matching the search for *Germany* and *Allows remote*.

Careers features such jobs quite prominently; jobs that allow for remote working are clearly labelled in all listings.